# angular1: How to wait for promise to resolve in parent controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I've searched for solutions for this but nothing seems to work in my case.

I'm sharing data between two angular controllers in coffeescript like so:

```
angular.module('app').controller 'accountCtrl', ($scope, $state, accountFactory) ->

    Api.Account.get(token: $scope.current_user.account_id).$promise.then ((response) ->
        accountFactory.set(response)
        $scope.account = accountFactory.account
    )

angular.module('app').controller 'accountPaymentMethodsCtrl', ($scope, $state, Api, accountFactory) ->

    $scope.account = accountFactory.account
    $scope.displayedPaymentMethods = [].concat($scope.account.payment_methods)
```

And I store the data in a factory like so:

```
angular.module('app').factory 'accountFactory', ->

    account = {
        payment_methods: {}

        set: (account) ->
            @account = account
            @account.payment_methods = account.payment_methods
    }

    account
```

Here's the problem:
When I refresh the page,

```
$scope.displayedPaymentMethods = [].concat($scope.account.payment_methods)
```

throws

> cannot read property 'payment_methods' of undefined

because $scope.account in the parent controller hasn't resolved yet. How do I get this line

```
$scope.displayedPaymentMethods = [].concat($scope.account.payment_methods)
```

and others to run after $scope.account in the parent controller has been resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, wrap below API call to function

```
Api.Account.get(token: $scope.current_user.account_id).$promise.then ((response) ->
    accountFactory.set(response)
    $scope.account = accountFactory.account
)
```

and in `accountPaymentMethodsCtrl` call this function and wait for promise to resolve like you've done in `accountCtrl`.

This will work :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Store your account information using 'local storage' or 'cookie' and retrieve the data

Answer (score 0):

If the parent controller and child controller on different routes then you can use the route resolve to make the child controller wait. https://johnpapa.net/route-resolve-and-controller-activate-in-angularjs/

If they are not, then I would suggest writing a factory to store the data and utilize that in both controllers.